# How can I traverse a mega menu using hover events in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am building a mega menu style navigation using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.
See code pen here.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZoBYz

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
      <div id="menu-wrapper">
        <ul>
          <li><a id="item-1-button" href="#">Item 1</a></li><li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li><li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="mega-menu">
      <div id="mega-menu-wrapper">
        <div id="item-1-menu">
          <ul>
            <li>Child list item 1</li>
            <li>Child list item 2</li>
            <li>Child list item 3</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

div#menu {
  position: relative;
  background: #DDD;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
}

div#menu ul{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

div#menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

div#menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #AAA;
}

div#menu-wrapper {
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}

div#mega-menu {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: #AAA;
  display: none;
}

div#mega-menu-wrapper {
  width: 900px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}

div#item-1-menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

div#item-1-menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var itemOneButton = document.getElementById("item-1-button");
var itemOneMenu = document.getElementById("item-1-menu");
var megaMenu = document.getElementById("mega-menu");

var hoveringItemOne = false;
var hoveringMegaMenu = false;

itemOneButton.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  hoveringItemOne = true;
  changeMenu("item1");
}, true);

itemOneButton.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  hoveringItemOne = false;
  changeMenu();
}, true);

megaMenu.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  hoveringMegaMenu = true;
  changeMenu();
}, true);

megaMenu.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  hoveringMegaMenu = false;
  changeMenu();
}, true);

function changeMenu(menuItem) {
  if(menuItem === "item1") {
    showItem1Menu()
  }

  if(hoveringItemOne == false && hoveringMegaMenu == false) {
    hideItem1Menu();
  }
}

function showItem1Menu() {
  megaMenu.style.display = 'block';
  itemOneMenu.style.display = 'block';
}

function hideItem1Menu() {
  megaMenu.style.display = 'none';
  itemOneMenu.style.display = 'none';
}
```

If you hover Item 1 in the menu, the mega menu for that menu item will appear. The problem is that when I try to hover from the menu item down to the mega menu, it will disappear even though the two are right beside each other.

Im using boolean variables to control the visibility of the mega menu because I eventually want to have the menu work from item 1, 2, 3, or more menu items.

I have also tried this variation where I set both of the following variables to true when hovering the first menu item.
- hoveringItemOne
- hoveringMegaMenu
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLGYOE

```
itemOneButton.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  hoveringItemOne = true;
  hoveringMegaMenu = true;
  changeMenu("item1");
}, true);
```

A problem with this variation is that the hover value of the variable hoveringMegaMenu variable is disturbed by its child elements. It also stays true forever if the mega menu that appears is never touched.

Is there a better way of developing a mega menu like this? The point is to be able to interact with anything inside the mega menu continaer until the cursor leaves either the mega menu spanning the entire width of the page, or until another menu item is hovered, which would reveal a new set of content.

Comment: This is not an answer, but if you feel like considering a different approach: http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/lEghe

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this

```js
var itemOneButton = document.getElementById("item-1-button");
var itemOneMenu = document.getElementById("item-1-menu");
var megaMenu = document.getElementById("mega-menu");

var hoveringItemOne = false;

itemOneButton.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  hoveringItemOne = true;
});
itemOneButton.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  hoveringItemOne = false;
});
megaMenu.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  hoveringItemOne = true;
});
megaMenu.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  hoveringItemOne = false;
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
  if (hoveringItemOne) {
    megaMenu.style.display = "block";
    itemOneMenu.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    megaMenu.style.display = "none";
    itemOneMenu.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

div#menu {
  position: relative;
  background: #DDD;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
}

div#menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

div#menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

div#menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #AAA;
}

div#menu-wrapper {
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}

div#mega-menu {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: #AAA;
  display: none;
}

div#mega-menu-wrapper {
  width: 900px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}

div#item-1-menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

div#item-1-menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div id="menu-wrapper">
    <ul>
      <li><a id="item-1-button" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="mega-menu">
  <div id="mega-menu-wrapper">
    <div id="item-1-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>Child list item 1</li>
        <li>Child list item 2</li>
        <li>Child list item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AK_Spikey/e9dL6mx9/)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Wondering how I could make this solution work for 2 or more menu items, not just the one.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but It seems like you can get away with a bit less code - and maybe even leave out the JavaScript. Check out this codePen: http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/XKZpJR?editors=0100

There are times where the sub-menus need to be separate, (in which case you would need to watch interaction with JavaScript) - but you can often put them each in their list-item parent and use the wonderful `position: relative;` and `position: absolute;` relational positioning.

### markup

```
<ul class='menu'>

    <li>
        <a href="">Dirt Nap</a>
        <ul class='sub-menu'>
            <li><a href="">Heart Felt</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Moon Belt</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Belted out</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Outgoing</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Closet Deserter</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    ...
```

### styles

(you can turn them to CSS in the codepen)

```
ul
    list-style: none
    margin: 0
    padding: 0

.big-ugly-monstrosity
    width: 100%
    float: left
    background: $color
    .menu
        position: relative
        width: 100%
        float: left // should be clear-fix
        a //
            display: block
            padding: $pad
            &:hover
                background: rgba(0,0,0,.1)
        li
            float: left
        > li
            //
            &:hover
                .sub-menu
                    display: block
            &:nth-of-type(2n +2)
                .sub-menu // to show stacked sub-menu items...
                    li //
                        width: 100%
    .sub-menu
        display: none
        position: absolute
        top: 100%
        left: 0
        width: 100%
        background: $highlight
```

I would encourage you to do something like this instead though: http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/lEghe

I think that hover/ drop-down menus are a pretty lousy user-interface now that we have touch screens and such varied devices.

If you do go with JavaScript, you can associate the 'tabs' and their sub-menus with `rel='tab1'` or `data-tab='1'` and get the data-attr on hover and use it to show the `data-sub='1'` that it's associated with.